# Count of duplicate values by two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

From this table:

```
Number Value
1      a
2      b
3      a
2      c
2      b
3      a
2      b
```

I need to get count of all duplicate rows by `Number` and `Value`, i.e. 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need duplicate count of two columns..?

Comment: Despite the simple data set, I actually don't understand your question.  What is your expected output here?

Comment: How do you get the result as `3`?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a misprint here, I want to get 5: 3 strings `2  b` and two strings `3  a`

Comment: @Feofilakt : Please explain... How 5?

Comment: @Feofilakt : If 3 strings `2, b` means 2 duplicates right?

Comment: If your intention is count of all duplicate **rows** then you could try my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this query is what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(t.cnt)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY number, value
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)t;
```

Comment: Yes, this has helped. And what does `t` in the end means?

Comment: @Feofilakt `t` is only an alias Name

Comment: @Feofilakt  As [Tim Biegeleisen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) said, you'd better provide not only sample data, but also desired result in op next time . Or like so many answers, only one can get your point.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
select value,number,max(cnt) as Count_distinct from (
      select *,row_number () over (partition by value,number order by number) as cnt
     from #sample
     )t
     group by value,number
```

**Output**

```
   +---------------------------------+
   | Value | Number | Count_Distinct |
   |   a   |   1    |        1       |
   |   b   |   2    |        3       |
   |   c   |   2    |        1       |
   |   a   |   3    |        2       |
   +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: It's exactly what I need for my other purpose! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    count(distinct Number) as Distinct_Numbers,
    count(distinct Value) as Distinct_Values
from 
    Table
```

This shows how many distinct values are in each column. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean number of unique number - value pairs, you can use:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, value ORDER BY (select 1)) from mytable rnk) i
where i.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number partition by both the columns and order by both the columns. Then count the number of rows where row number greater than 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [Number], [Value]
        order by [Number], [Value]
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select count(*) from cte
where [rn] > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this query may help you

select * from [dbo].[Sample_table1]

;WITH
DupContactRecords(number,value,DupsCount)
AS
(
SELECT number,value, COUNT(*) AS TotalCount FROM [Sample_table1] GROUP BY number,value HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
--to get the duplicats
/*select * from DupContactRecords*/
SELECT sum(DupsCount) FROM DupContactRecords[image]